# Adding in python

Tags: python, loops

```
while i<10:
   a = a + i
   print (a)
   i = i+1
```

or

```
for i in range(10):
   sum = sum + i
   print
```

---

```
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
```

Then how can I add them together by writing further codes?
I mean 1+3+6+10+15+21+... Then set the total as variables!
That would be great if you can show me in both loop :)

Comment: Do not call your variable sum; that's the name of a built-in function. (And you might want to type `help(sum)` at the interpreter console, because it may help you here.)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
total, totaltotal = 0, 0
for i in range(10):
  total += i
  totaltotal += total
  print total, totaltotal
```

Alternatively, you can make a list of the totals and store them to operate on separately:

```
total, totals = 0, []
for i in range(10):
  total += i
  totals.append(total)
  print total
totaltotal = 0
for i in range(10):
  totaltotal += totals[i]
  print totaltotal
```

You may want to rewrite this as a list comprehension (or even a generator expression), as a useful exercise.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [26]: summ=0

In [27]: foo=0       

In [28]: for i in range(10):
    sum+=i          #add i to summ
    foo+=sum        #add summ to foo
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [31]: sum
Out[31]: 45

In [32]: foo
Out[32]: 165
```

or a one-liner:

```
In [58]: sum(map(sum,map(range,range(1,11))))
Out[58]: 165
```

`timeit` comparisons:

```
In [56]: %timeit sum(sum(i + 1 for i in range(n)) for n in range(1000))
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit sum(map(sum,map(range,range(1,1001))))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
sum(sum(i + 1 for i in range(n)) for n in range(10))
```

(if you want a pythonic approach)